# How to filter array by object value and return a new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filtering

I am having a hard time in finding a way to filter this array by id value, and generate a new one preserving coords with it's filter.

Array example:

```
var herbs =[
{
"coords":[3300,2796],"items":[
{id: "dandelion",qty: 72},
{id: "sage",qty: 4},
{id: "valerian",qty: 1},
]},
{
"coords":[3300,2800],"items":[
{id: "dandelion",qty: 26},
{id: "valerian",qty: 7},
{id: "sage",qty: 2},
]},
{
"coords":[3300,2804],"items":[
{id: "dandelion",qty: 57},
{id: "sage",qty: 4},
{id: "wormwood",qty: 1},
]}]
```

I want to filter it by id, generating a new one with it's coords.

Example:

Filtering by `id = dandelion`

```
var dandelion =[
{
"coords":[3300,2796],"items":[
{id: "dandelion",qty: 72},
]},
{
"coords":[3300,2800],"items":[
{id: "dandelion",qty: 26},
]},
{
"coords":[3300,2804],"items":[
{id: "dandelion",qty: 57},
]}]
```

Filtering by `id = sage`

```
var sage =[
{
"coords":[3300,2796],"items":[
{id: "sage",qty: 4},
]},
{
"coords":[3300,2800],"items":[
{id: "sage",qty: 2},
]},
{
"coords":[3300,2804],"items":[
{id: "sage",qty: 4},
]}]
```

Also, this array it's pretty big, I have 467.000 coords. So I plan to filter it and save a new file with each filtered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` for this to push to a new array with `items` the result of a `filter` within the reduce call. It only pushes to the new array when the search term is found somewhere in the `items`:

```js
var herbs =[
    {
    "coords":[3300,2796],"items":[
    {id: "dandelion",qty: 72},
    {id: "sage",qty: 4},
    {id: "valerian",qty: 1},
    ]},
    {
    "coords":[3300,2800],"items":[
    {id: "dandelion",qty: 26},
    {id: "valerian",qty: 7},
    {id: "sage",qty: 2},
    ]},
    {
    "coords":[3300,2804],"items":[
    {id: "dandelion",qty: 57},
    {id: "sage",qty: 4},
    {id: "wormwood",qty: 1},
    ]}]

function filterByID(array, id) {
    return array.reduce((a, c) => {
        let items = c.items.filter(i => i.id === id )
        if (items.length){
            a.push({
            coords: c.coords,
            items: items
            })
        }
        return a
    }, [])
}    


console.log(filterByID(herbs, "dandelion"))
console.log(filterByID(herbs, "sage"))
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Didn't knew the reduce method! Thank you very much @Mark_M

Answer (score 0):

It is very straightforward. Use standard `Array` methods `map` and `filter` to get what you want.

```js
var herbs = [{
    "coords": [3300, 2796],
    "items": [{
        id: "dandelion",
        qty: 72
      },
      {
        id: "sage",
        qty: 4
      },
      {
        id: "valerian",
        qty: 1
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "coords": [3300, 2800],
    "items": [{
        id: "dandelion",
        qty: 26
      },
      {
        id: "valerian",
        qty: 7
      },
      {
        id: "sage",
        qty: 2
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "coords": [3300, 2802],
    "items": [{
        id: "dandelion",
        qty: 26
      },
      {
        id: "valerian",
        qty: 7
      },
      //no sage
    ]
  },
  {
    "coords": [3300, 2804],
    "items": [{
        id: "dandelion",
        qty: 57
      },
      {
        id: "sage",
        qty: 4
      },
      {
        id: "wormwood",
        qty: 1
      },
    ]
  }
];

function filterHerbs(id) {
  return herbs.map((h) => {
      return {
        coords: h.coords,
        items: h.items.filter((i) => i.id == id)
      }
    })//filter result in case of empty item arrays
    .filter((h) => h.items.length);
}
var dand = filterHerbs('dandelion')
console.log(dand);
var sage = filterHerbs('sage');
console.log(sage);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const dandelion = herbs.map(
    ({coords, items}) => items.filter(
        ({id}) => id === 'dandelion'
).map(ob => ({coords, ...ob})));
```